# How can I write list.GroupBy(x => x.AccountNumber).Select(g => g.First()) without LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I need to analyze a task that starts with the code below but I couldn't figure out what the LINQ part is doing. Any leads are appreciated

```
foreach (var item in list.GroupBy(x => x.AccountNumber).Select(g => g.First()))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us why this code written?

Comment: [`GroupBy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) [`Select`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) [`First`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_First__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__)

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs I linked above?

Comment: `GroupBy(x => x.AccountNumber).Select(g => g.First())` will remove any duplicate entities based on `AccountNumber`. Kinda like `Distinct()` would

Comment: That *is* C#. This code picks the first item in the list for each AccountNumber

Comment: @rak007 no it won't. That's `Distinct()`'s job. `First()` returns the first element per AccountNumber, no matter what the other properties of that item contain

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think that's what they meant by "kinda"...

Comment: @canton7 now that I saw that MoreLINQ calls the operator `DistinctBy` instead of `FirstBy` I have to agree that yes, kinda. I had to search a bit to find it though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some roughly-equivalent code (i.e. has the same function, but works slightly differently) would be:

```
var seenAccountNumbers = new HashSet<int>(); // Or some other data type?
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if (seenAccountNumbers.Add(item.AccountNumber))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is exactly how MoreLinq's DistinctBy works. I guess the downvoter isn't as familiar with LINQ

Comment: does Add function return bool?

Comment: @snr do I really have to flag this comment? English please. And the `IList<T>.Add` method implemented by most containers *doesn't* return anything. `HashSet.Add` does to indicate whether it actually added something or not

Comment: @aliihsanmuhziroğlu [Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=netframework-4.8). It returns `true` if the element was added to the `HashSet<T>`, or `false` if the element was already present in the `HashSet<T>`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're right sir, it happened intuitively.

Answer (score 3):

This code is a (somewhat wasteful) way of getting the first item by account number. It's wasteful because there's no reason to group everything before trying to find the first item per group.

The same thing can be implemented with an iterator function by iterating over all items in the input list and keeping track of all the AccountNumber values found so far. When a new one is found, yield it and add it to the tracking list. Or rather, HashSet.

In fact, that's how [MoreLinq's DistinctBy](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) operator is implemented :

```
var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
foreach (var element in source)
{
    if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        yield return element;
}
```

From the method's description:

> Returns all distinct elements of the given source, where "distinctness"is determined via a projection and the default equality comparer for the projected type.
>
> If a key is seen multiple times, only the first element with that key is returned.

The question's code can be replaced with :

```
foreach (var item in list.DistinctBy(x => x.AccountNumber))
{...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary, with the AccountNumber as Key, and put all your items from list, in that dictionary. That is about what happens.

You will overwrite items, with the same key, and a randomly last element, will stay in the dictionary. There is no order ensured when using GroupBy, so it doesn't matter if you choose First or Last element at the end, it just has the meaning of "pick one" (random).

```
  var dict = new Dictionary<KeyType, ElementType>();
  foreach(var item in list)
      if (!dict.ContainsKey(item.AccountNumber))
           dict[item.AccountNumber] = item;
```

You original iteration would now be

```
  foreach(var item in dict.Values)
  {
      .....
  }
```

To ask for Non-LINQ solution is not so strange, cause LINQ offers never the most performant solution, it's just short writing and fast coding.

Comment: Your solution does the opposite of what the OP's code does. Theirs gets the *first* account for each account number, and yours gets the *last*. The order from `GroupBy` *is* ensured: "*Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in `source`.*" ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__))

Comment: As my comment just above explains (and links you to the relevant doc), `GroupBy` *does* guarantee the order of items in a group, and it's the order they appeared in the source collection

Comment: @canton, OK, than I put this one more line in. If applied to a SQL-Database, the order is undefined or random, cause the original collection has no order.

Comment: Also, the order of `Values` in a dictionary *is* undefined (in this case, it happens to be insertion order in the current implementation, but that is not guaranteed in future). So your answer also differs from the OP's code in that it yields the groups in a potentially different order. The correct way to write this code is using a `HashSet`, as is done in @PanagiotisKanavos's answer

Comment: You can check at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8
explicitly: *It does not preserve a particular order* also *HashSet<T> class can be thought of as a Dictionary<TKey,TValue> collection without values*. Is it your intention to declare me as completely stupid ? You are right, Hashset is accidently preserving the order, but this is not a documented feature, it's an observable behaviour of the current implementation that might be subject to change.

Comment: Please read @PanagiotisKanavos's answer: they're not relying on the *order* of elements in the `HashSet` at all. That's the point: you cannot rely on the order of either `HashSet` or `Dictionary`

Comment: I did, and it's about the same approach in another syntax. We answered in parallel. It differs in no way from my answer. He uses an iterator function, I store it. So I agree, iterators might be preferrable- but on the other hand, if a beginner is asking "what's going on" its more difficult to understand. One who does not know LINQ may also not know `yield`. There is a pedagogical idea behind my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206151/discussion-between-canton7-and-holger).

Comment: Please keep the discussion in the linked chat